# (Forge) Instantiating a new class that extends ItemAxe doesn’t work

Tags: java, class, minecraft-forge

I am creating a Minecraft 1.12.2 mod (forge 1.12.2-
14.23.1.2555) and I have created a new class that extends ItemAxe. When I instantiate the new class into a variable, the variable returns null. Therefore, when the item is registered, a NullPointerException is thrown. I came down to this after I tried changing the extension of ItemAxe to ItemPickaxe. Ran the code, it worked. Changed it back to ItemAxe, ran the code, didn’t work. The source code for the ItemAxe class I made is the exact same as the ItemPickaxe class I also made, except that Pickaxe was replaced with Axe in the ItemAxe class, of course. I know I am not using the latest version of Forge for 1.12.2, but I am using this version as it has worked better for me when it comes to running the code from the IDE. Any way to fix this? I know this is a known bug...

Source:

```java
// CustomAxe.java

public class CustomAxe extends ItemAxe {
    public CustomAxe(ToolMaterial material, String name) {
        super(material);
        this.setRegistryName(name);
        this.setUnlocalizedName(name);
        this.setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.TOOLS);
    }

}
```

```java
// Main.java

public static Item austroneAxe;
public static ToolMaterial austrone;

@EventHandler
public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) 
{
    austrone = EnumHelper.addToolMaterial(“austrone”, 4, 2007, 12.0F, 66.0F, 30);

    austroneAxe = new CustomAxe(austrone, “austrone_axe”);

}
```

```java
// CommonProxy.java
@SubscribeEvent
public static void registerItems(RegistryEvent.Register<Item> event) {
   event.getRegistry().registerAll(Main.austroneAxe); // Exception thrown here

}
```

Comment: Could you provide the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching the issue a little bit more, I solved the problem.

The default `super` constructor doesn’t work for ItemAxe. Therefore, you must use the secondary constructor, where you must provide a ToolMaterial, a float for attack damage, and a float for attack speed. In my case, the following line of code worked for me:

```java
super(material, material.getAttackDamage,1.0F);
```

Comment: Answering your own question ... surely big-brain it is.